Intution behind $\mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V, W) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(U, \mathrm{Hom}(V, W)). $
I'm currently self-studying Tensor products and came across this result:
$$
\mathrm{Hom}(U\otimes V, W) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(U, \mathrm{Hom}(V, W)).
$$
Whilst I can follow the proof algebraically, I can't really see the big picture.
What is the best way to intutively understand this result, and other results related to the tensor product.
My current understanding of the tensor product is that it allows us to linearise bilinear maps. However, beyond this I don't have much understanding.
*I have not studied modules or category theory so I would be grateful if the answers stay in the realm of linear algebra.

The trick is probably to understand the elements of $\operatorname{Hom}(U, \operatorname{Hom}(V,W))$. If $f$ is such an element it gives us a family of linear maps $f(u) : V \to W$ indexed by $U$. But we can also look at those as bilinear maps $(u,v) \mapsto f(u)(v)$ from $U \times V$ to $W$. Going from a bilinear map $g : U \times V \to W$ to a family of maps $g_u : V \to W$ indexed by $U$ is similar. Writing out what's going on here should give you the bijection.

You should be able to understand first the following statement
$$\mathsf{Fun}(X\times Y,Z)\simeq\mathsf{Fun}(X,\mathsf{Fun}(Y,Z))$$
where $\mathsf{Fun}(A,B)$ is the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$.  The idea is that any function $f$ from $X$ to $\mathsf{Fun}(Y,Z)$ gives you for each $x\in X$, a function $f(x)\colon Y\to Z$. This is the same as saying, for every pair $(x,y)\in X\times Y$, $f$ assigns a value in $Z$, which is $f(x)(y)$. This also works backwards of course, hence the bijection.
In your cases, replace functions by homomorphisms, then the same thing holds. A homomorphism from $X$ to $\mathsf{Fun}(Y,Z)$ can be seen as a bilinear map $X\times Y\to Z$, which factors into a unique map from $X\otimes Y$ to $Z$. And of course, you can make any map out of $X\times Y$ to $Z$ into a map from $X$ to $\mathsf{Fun}(Y,Z)$ in a similar fashion. That gives the natural isomorphism as well.
Hope this helps. :)
